# WPF how to set column to page width and at the end create a new row?

Tags: c#, wpf, position

**Problem**

I am trying to display the grids so that they are next to each other. But when the end of the window has been reached, a new row should be created. For now I only achieved that they are under each other, and that I manually set the columns so that maybe 4 are beside each other.

XAML markup:

```
<Page x:Class="StoreManagment.Manager.EmployeesView"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StoreManagment.Manager"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="EmployeesView" Background="White">

<ScrollViewer >
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel >
        <Label Content="Mitarbeiter" FontSize="20" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,0,0">

            <Button Content="Alle" Name="AlleButton" Style="{StaticResource FilterButton}" Click="AlleButton_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Angestellte" Name="AngestellteButton" Style="{StaticResource FilterButton}"/>
            <Button Content="Auszubildende" Name="AuszubildendeButton" Style="{StaticResource FilterButton}"/>
            <Button Content="Abteilungsleiter" Name="AbteilungsleiterButton" Style="{StaticResource FilterButton}"/>


        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>

    <Button Name="AddEmployeeButton" Content="Mitarbeiter Hinzufügen" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,0,0,0" Width="150" Height="20" Style="{StaticResource FilterButton}" Click="AddEmployeeButton_Click" />
    
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding employeesList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkOrange" Height="110" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                        <Grid Margin="5,15,0,0">

                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                                <Label Content="Id:" />
                                <Label Content="Vorname:" />
                                <Label Content="Nachname:" />
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Label FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="{Binding Id}" />
                                <Label FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="{Binding Vorname}" />
                                <Label FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="{Binding Nachname}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Use a WrapPanel? Or UniformGrid? You have to make yourself familiar with the various layout Panels available in WPF.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks. If you have any tips regarding learning the layout Panels. then your help is welcomed. :)

Comment: There is online documentation available.